# How to cache an X509Certificate2 object

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate2, memorycache

We have an ASP.NET web API that reads a certificate from Azure Key Vault and afterwards loads the certificate into an `X509Certificate2` object.

We want to implement some caching since it's not making sense to download the certificate from Azure a lot of times. My initial instinct was to cache the byte array that represents the downloaded certificate. From reading more about the `X509Certificate2` class, I understand that the certificate needs to be written once to the temporary folder and afterwards loaded into the key store.

That said, I feel that caching only the byte array is suboptimal, and we should cache the `X509Certificate2` object.

We are using `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` as our cache.

My question is the following: are there any best practices on caching `X509Certificate2`? Is it safe to cache an `X509Certificate2`, or could it provoke some weird side effects?

Comment: Yes, best practice is not to 'cache' it as this poses a security risk. It should be loaded into memory when needed and destroyed (ideally zeroing out) immediately. That said, there is not enough information about your environment to recommend the best strategy. If you're running on Windows, AND you control the machine (e.g. it is not shared) you would benefit from loading the keys into a CSP as that typically is the safest way to store them on Windows.

Comment: We are using PAAS components like azure web apps so we don't have control over the underlying OS. Caching at least the bytes is the only efficient way to handle this use case since it's not recommend to request this data from azure key vault a lot of times, nor is it economical. Also I'm quite curios why this is not secure.  In theory the environments are sandbox so this means that there shouldn't be a way attackers can access this information.

Comment: Read up on spectre/meltdown attacks. Essentially, if you use PaaS, you share the physical hardware with some other people. If they manage to perform this kinds of attacks they could dump the bytes of your certificate keys.

Comment: Yes I know about those vectors. I  also read about the solarwinds hack :) . On the other hand, we are going into the premise that all cloud environments are already compromised. In the end the attacker would also need to infiltrate's the cloud environment to actually get hand on this bytes, and to somehow find out exactly the physical hardware were your software is running.